# Comprobar si existe correo en BD

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Verán tengo un formulario en el cual tengo nombre, apellido, dos campos correo(el segundo para verificar si es igual al primero),contraseña, y dos RadioButton con los sexos.

Lo que necesito es comprobar solo el correo si esta o no repetido en la BD.
los demás campos los valido con JQuery. Pero también voy a utilizar JQuery para comprobar que los dos correos sean iguales(en los dos campos).

Estoy utilizando PHP.

La primera pregunta es: La conexion a la bd la puedo hacer en un archivo aparte y utilizar "Include()"?? o la puedo utilizar en el mismo archivo donde valido el correo(donde envio el formulario con $_POST)?.

Me podrían ayudar con el código??No es que quiera que me lo hagan todo, Sino lo básico.**Solo comprobar el correo si ya existe en la BD.**

Comment: **1** Sí y también. **2** http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php y `select count(1) from NombreTabla where email = ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que puedes incluir la conexión a la base de datos en un archivo aparte con la función [include](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php).

Supongamos que nuestro archivo de conexión se llame `connection.php`

```
<?php
   $servername = "localhost";
   $user = "pepito";
   $password = "mipass";
   $dbname = "nombredebd";


   //Creamos la conexion a la base de datos
   $connection = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $dbname);

   //Verificamos la conexion a la BD. Si la conexion falla, nos mostrará el error, si no la conexión se estableció.
   if ($connection->connect_error) {
       die("La conexión fallo. Error: (".$connection->connect_errno.") ".$connection->connect_error);
   }
?>
```

Después procederemos a 'incluir' nuestro archivo `connection.php`, al archivo donde verificaremos si existe el correo en la base de datos o no.

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    //Como tu quieres utilizar el método POST, lo haremos de la siguiente manera. 
    //La variable $_SERVER es una variable reservada que incluye cierta información del propio servidor. 
    //Lo que quiere decir que el 'metodo de peticion' (REQUEST_METHOD) se utilizara solo SI la peticion es mediante POST.
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
         $correo = $_POST["correo"];

         //Procederemos a hacer una consulta que buscara el correo del usuario
         $buscarCorreo = "SELECT * from usuarios WHERE correo='$correo'";

         //Realizamos la consulta y anadimos $connection, ya que es la variable que creamos en nuestro archivo connection.php
         $resultado = $connection->query($buscarCorreo);

         //Usaremos la funcion mysqli_num_rows en la consulta $resultado,
         //esta funcion nos regresa el numero de filas en el resultado
         $contador = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

         //SI SI EXISTE una fila, quiere decir QUE SI ESTA EL CORREO EN LA BASE DE DATOS
         if($contador == 1) {
            echo 'El correo ya existe';
         } else {
         echo 'El correo no existe';
         }
    }
?>
```

Trato de explicarlo lo mejor que puedo, aún así, si tienes alguna duda dejame un comentario y no una respuesta. Así podré ayudarte u orientarte si tienes alguna duda más.

Comment: Esta forma se presta a [inyección SQL](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/127), deberías usar una sentencia preparada.

Comment: Gracias, Mariano. Hasta hace poco me entere de eso por una pregunta/respuesta de Alvaro. Aún no he tenido tiempo de leerla pero en cuanto tenga lo haré, porque es sumamente importante :)

Comment: @HooseUna preguntita.Entonces cuando me verifique que el correo no existe,a la hora de registrar en la BD,debo hacerlo dentro de "else"?

Comment: @Hoose .Entonces cuando me verifique que el correo no existe,a la hora de registrar en la BD,debo hacerlo dentro de "else"?

Comment: @luis asi es, usarias una consulta insert para poder ingresar un nuevo correo. Si crees que esta respuesta te a sido útil, por favor aceptala. Saludos!

Comment: @Hoose Pero no me funciona.No agrega nada.Estoy en phpmyadmin.Lo tengo en local.sin ningún password.Pongo la sentencia INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellido,correo,password) VALUES($user,$apellido,$email,$clave); Todo eso lo pongo dentro de "else",pero no me funciona nada.Ayudita

Comment: @luis Formula una nueva pregunta junto con el código, la tabla donde quieres hacer el insert y el error que te puede estar generando y con gusto te ayudamos. Saludos.